# Write select statement which should return all objects

Tags: oracle

I am new to Oracle. How can I write a select query which should return table names, column names, constraints, indexes, partitions for given schema name.

Answer (score 1):

We can get this information from the data dictionary:

- table names = `all_tables`
- column names = `all_tab_columns`
- constraints = `all_constraints`
- indexes = `all_indexes`
- partitions  = `all_tab_partitions`

For instance

```
select table_name
from all_tables
where owner = 'WHOEVER';
```

Here is a link to the definition of the data dictionary views in [the Oracle Reference guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-8865F65B-EF6D-44A5-B0A1-3179EFF0C36A.htm#REFRN002).

The `ALL_` views only sure the objects on which you have been granted privileges. If you have DBA privileges you can use the `DBA_` equivalent which shows all the objects in all schemas.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from what you've already been told, try to memorize the "**dictionary**" word; sometimes it is surprisingly useful.

For example, you need to find some info about constraints, but don't know which source to use - dictionary knows, just ask:

```
SQL> col comments format a48
SQL> select * from dictionary
  2  where lower(comments) like '%constraint%'
  3  order by table_name;

TABLE_NAME                     COMMENTS
------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------
ALL_CONS_COLUMNS               Information about accessible columns in constrai
                               nt definitions

ALL_CONSTRAINTS                Constraint definitions on accessible tables
USER_CONS_COLUMNS              Information about accessible columns in constrai
                               nt definitions

USER_CONSTRAINTS               Constraint definitions on user's own tables

SQL>
```

So,

- you could have read Oracle documentation and *learn* such things (which is the best option; nobody can steal your knowledge), or
- Google for it (which is what most people usually do and, you wouldn't believe it, succeed), or
- post a question somewhere on the Internet and wait for some good soul to bring you salvation, or
- give up, and go planting potatoes

Answer (score 0):

Oracle provides a host of views to inform you about the database structure. A few examples: user_tab_columns, v$tablespace and many others. Search Oracle "Tables Data Dictionary Views" for more.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response..I got good info on dictionary tables.I need one more help that , In a single select query we need all below info.                                                 Below details in single query.                         table names = all_tables
column names = all_tab_columns
constraints = all_constraints
indexes = all_indexes
partitions = all_tab_partitions